Terraform to create Appinsight Named value from Keyvault while creating the APIM ligger
We have below terraform code to create AzureAPIM logger configuration for the appinsight during the appinsight creation itself. But here we are facing challenge to configure the Appinsight Instrumentation Key as named value from one of existing keyvault.
Looking for both the appinsight and logger addition with namedvalue of instrumentation key (from kv) as part of the application insight creation itself and not through manual task of creating secret in Keyvault after creating the Appinsight.
resource "azurerm_application_insights" "appinsights" {
  name                       = var.appinsights_name
  location                   = var.location
  resource_group_name        = var.rg_name
  application_type           = var.application_type
  retention_in_days          = var.retention_in_days
  workspace_id               = data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.laworkspace.id
  internet_ingestion_enabled = var.internet_ingestion_enabled
  disable_ip_masking         = var.disable_ip_masking
  
  tags = var.appinsights_tags

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      tags,
      disable_ip_masking
    ]
  }
}


resource "azurerm_api_management_logger" "logger" {
  count = var.add_to_apim ? 1 : 0

  api_management_name = var.apim_name
  resource_group_name = var.apim_rg
  name                = azurerm_application_insights.appinsights.name
  resource_id         = azurerm_application_insights.appinsights.id

  application_insights {
    instrumentation_key = azurerm_application_insights.appinsights.instrumentation_key
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      resource_id
    ]
  }
}


You can use the azurerm_api_management_named_value resource to manages an API Management Named Value,
The value_from_key_vault block can be used to link an Azure Key Vault secret.
Example (not tested):
resource "azurerm_api_management_named_value" "example" {
  name         = "example-apimg"
  display_name = "ExampleProperty"

  resource_group_name = var.apim_rg
  api_management_name = var.apim_name

  value_from_key_vault {
    secret_id = var.secret_id
  }

  secret = true
}


But whether this will accept the app insight block in the apim logger to get the instrumentation key from this named value?
